# Sybase performance issue: INSERT SELECT

Tags: sql, database, performance, sybase

I'm new to Sybase and we're having trouble in query performance. Hope someone can help.

The problematic code is similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO #table
    SELECT lt.id, rt.id
    FROM local_table lt
    JOIN remote_table rt ON rt.id = lt.id
    WHERE ...
```

There's a join between local user table and a local view which references a proxy table located in another database. The proxy table is connecting to another server. The query is basically joining local and remote tables and inserting the result in a temporary table.

Even if it will insert 0 record, the query takes forever to execute.

Some observations are:

- If I remove the insert statement, the SELECT query executes fast.
- If I convert the statement to SELECT INTO, the query runs fine.
- If the query is split into two, (INSERT SELECT from remote table, then DELETE extra records not existing in local table) the query runs fine.

Is there perhaps a configuration setting that can boost performance of queries like this so there will be no code changes? What would be the best approach to handle this?

I'll appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

**Edit:** By the way, on our trace it is issuing this kind of wait:

> waiting for CTLIB event to complete

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `select into`?

Comment: Hi Michael, coz it would introduce code change on many stored procedures all over the database! I wondering if there was a less painful way to solve this issue with minimal effort. Thanks for dropping by.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow these steps:

- check out the query plan (set showplan on) and see if that makes sense
- run update statistics on the table and the proxy table and see if that gives a better query plan
- See if enabling join relocation gives a better query plan: run "sp_dboption yourdb, 'join relocation', true" in the local server and "sp_dboption tempdb, 'ddl in tran', true" in the remote server
- in case you need to see the full interaction with the remote server, run "dbcc traceon(11205)", this will log the interaction in the ASE errorlog

After these steps you should at least have a much better idea what's going on and why, if not have the issue solved.

Comment: Hi RobV, thanks for sharing your expertise.

I can't see the option in your third bullet: run "sp_dboption yourdb, 'join relocation', true".

Would like to try this one. I'm using Sybase ASE 15.7. Can you help?

Comment: When I try to run:
exec sp_dboption <dbname>, 'join relocation', true

It generates "The database option does not exist or you cannot set the option."

Comment: Apologies, it is: sp_serveroption <remote-server-name>, 'relocated joins', true

Comment: Hi RobV, I tried the 'relocated joins' in local server and enable 'ddl tran' in remote server but the query is still slow. Guess, I need the code change to break the query into two.